# How to get Date object in “YYYY-MM-DD” format in android

Tags: android, date, datetime

I have a requirement that I need to compare two Dates. One Date will come from DB which is String in "YYYY-DD-MM" firm and I need to compare this String Date with current Date.

for this I am converting Date String into Date object.

Now I need current Date also in "YYYY-MM-DD" format and it should be Date object so that I can use.compareTo() method compare two dates..

Please help me how to do that...

Comment: There are several valid answers on this thread, you should accept one...

Answer (score 65):

```
 Date cDate = new Date();
 String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cDate);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in following way

```
// pick current system date

    Date dt = new Date();

// set format for date

   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

 // parse it like

        String check = dateFormat.format(dt);


        System.out.println("DATE TO FROM DATEBASE   " + 
                arrayOfStringDate[d].toString());
        System.out.println("CURRENT DATE   " + check);
```

// and compare like

```
System.out.println("compare    "+ 
        arrayOfStringDate[d].toString().equals(check));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String time=DB time;
Date parseTime= tf.parse(time);
Integer dayNow=c.getTime().getDate();
Integer dayDb=parseTime.getDate();
```

then you can compare `dayNow` and `dayDb`.

Answer (score 4):

If your current date is actually an instance of the `java.util.Date` class, you don't need to specify a format for it; it's just a millisecond value that represents a specific moment in time.

You can get the current date like so:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use 2 ways:

1. [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) object. Use parse method.
2. Make your own parser of the Date. I mean, you convert the year, month and day in an integer each, and use [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) constructor to get the Date.

Answer (score 0):

You can call SimpleDateFormat , and from simpledateformat you will access to current date in string forme.

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String currentTime=simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    Log.d("Currentdate",currentdate);
```