# DateFormats in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

How can you convert the date in this format `mm/dd/yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd` when saving data to SQLite database in Android?

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/3778471/870450

Comment: I'd suggest not saving as a string....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312889/how-to-get-date-object-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-android/10345615#10345615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat  new_format= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");

Date date;
String local_date = null;
try{
    date = sdf.parse(value);

    local_date = new_format.format(date);

}catch(ParseException e)
{

e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Calendar object then.

```
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
```

You can retrieve same using

```
      long date=cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("expired_date"));
      Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.clear();
      cal.setTimeInMillis(date);
```

For various date format refer this link 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

```
     Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
     String date_time=String.format("%1$tY  %1$tB %1$te,%1$tI:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$Tp",cal);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date_time,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: check this link also  http://sberka.blogspot.in/2009/07/date-time-sqlite-and-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this code.. This will solve all your queries regarding date time conversion..

```
    public static String convertDateStringFormat(String currentFormat,
            String newFormat, String strDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(currentFormat);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            CommonFunctions.DoCatchOperation(e);
        }

        String newFormatString = convertDateToString(newFormat, date);
        return newFormatString;
    }

    public static Date convertStringToDate(String dateFormatter, String strDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatter);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            CommonFunctions.DoCatchOperation(e);
        }
        return date;
    }

    public static String convertDateToString(String dateFormatter, Date date) {
        if (date == null)
            return "";
        else {
            SimpleDateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatter);
            return dFormat.format(date);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String formatDate(String value) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy",
            Locale.US);

    Date date;
    String dateformat = "";
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(value);
        sdf.applyPattern("yyyy-mm-dd");
        dateformat = sdf.format(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }

    return dateformat;

}
```